# Using tableView function scrollToRow it crashed

Tags: ios

When a tableView is scrolling I update dataSource and invoke tableView function `reloadData`. After tableView `DidEndDecelerating` I invoke the function:

```
let indexPath = IndexPath(row: row, section: 0)
if row < dataModels.count {
   tableView.scrollToRow(at: indexPath, at: .top, animated: true)
}
```

Sometimes it will crash. The crash log likes below:

```
0 CoreFoundation  __exceptionPreprocess

1 libobjc.A.dylib objc_exception_throw

2 CoreFoundation +[_CFXNotificationTokenRegistration keyCallbacks]

3 Foundation -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:]

4 UIKitCore -[UITableViewRowData _assertValidIndexPath:allowEmptySection:]

5 UIKitCore -[UITableViewRowData ensureHeightsFaultedInForScrollToIndexPath:withScrollPosition:boundsHeight:]

6 UIKitCore -[UITableView _contentOffsetForScrollingToRowAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:usingPresentationValues:]

7 UIKitCore -[UITableView _scrollToRowAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:animated:usingPresentationValues:]

8 UIKitCore -[UITableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:animated:]
```

Answer (score 1):

First check the `indexpath` is exist or not. The call `scrollToRow` method.

```
extension UITableView {
    func isExist(indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
        if indexPath.section >= self.numberOfSections {
            return false
        }
        if indexPath.row >= self.numberOfRows(inSection: indexPath.section) {
            return false
        }
        return true
    }
}


func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    if !scrollView.isDecelerating {
        let indexPath = IndexPath(row: row, section: 0)
        if tableView.isExist(indexPath: indexPath) {
          tableView.scrollToRow(at: indexPath, at: .top, animated: true)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I just wonder that I have judged rows less than dataModels count. So how can prove this judgement is not always right?

Comment: Your crush due to mismatch of your dataModels count and number of cells of tableView. You can produce a scenario like that, update your dataModels and without reload table view then scroll to last index of the dataModels.

Comment: Once I update dataModels, I invoke the function reloadData. So I think dataModels count always match number of cells.

Comment: There is no delegate which ensure that tableview is finished relaod or not. So after update dataModels you invoke reload data and scrollToRow method. There is no guarantee that scrollToRow method called after finishing relaoding. That's why inconsistency occurs.

Comment: I set dataModels and reload data all in main thread. And the delegate number of rows also synchronous execute. So how can the function scrollToRow execute between the function setData and numberOfRows.